# Firebase data loading is slow in Flutter application

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on E-Grocery Store application, and found that when my application is loading data fast in debug mode, but when I install release apk of my project, then it takes too much time to load data, sometimes it does not load anything, I don't have any idea why this happening. I am Giving video example to easily understand my issue.

In Debug App:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PjYSoPKDsSPBayHe0kr1pewhG6moXw7e/view?usp=sharing

In Release App:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q5zp2twMRThLVSdqcz0cMB9hZEC_ZB8E/view?usp=sharing

Sometimes it takes 2-3 minutes to load data and sometimes it only show circular progress bar, And this happening only in release mode, app working nicely in debug version.

Comment: i got this because of this plugin =>  add_2_calendar: ^2.1.0.  after removing this app working perfectly fine in release mode too. Did you solve this? then pls do let me know

Comment: No, i leave it! I didn't find any appropriate solution yet

Comment: I currently have exactly same issue with the latest version of firestore `cloud_firestore: ^3.1.13` . It loads perfectly in debug mode but extremely slow in release mode.   Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, It's pretty wierd why this happening but with my case sometimes my data loads quickly and sometimes it's taking very long time with 10mbps speed so for now there is no any proper solution I found on it.